# In javascript, query.setQuery() select column multiply a user defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

In javascript for goolechart, I want to select a column times a user defined variable in `query.setQuery()`. For example, `query.setQuery('SELECT A, I*5')` is working, and will return all the values multiplied by 5 on the I column. 
  However, I want to have a user-defined varible: 
  `var val = 5`; 
and how should I use this variable val inside the query: `query.setQuery('SELECT A, I*val')` is not working.

Comment: have you tried `query.setQuery('SELECT A, I*' + val)` ?